# As a new graduate, what strategies I should follow to get hired as soon as possible?

Tags: career-development, job-search, careers

I will be graduating this April & I don't really want to be stay idle though I would spend my idle time working on side projects. Moreover I do have 3 internship experiences as a Web Developer. What strategies I should be following so as to get hired as soon as possible?

Comment: Are you hoping to work for different companies or one of the three you interned with? Are you hoping for _anything_?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Well I did two internships with one company and other with a different company. The Former knows that I will be graduating soon but I haven't talked to them about any job there.

Comment: @enderland Well, I did hope to work for the company where I did my two internships (sorry I didn't mention that in the question) but I am not sure about them because of some reasons.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I did actually, I will visit the office in person too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are more than a few ideas that come to mind:

1. School resources - Does your school have an area where employers could post jobs for recent graduates? This would definitely be an option to explore that may help you find a job as this is how I found my first job after graduating.
2. Networking groups - Are there groups or associations in your geographic area that may be useful for forming contacts, mentors and other possible opportunities? Here in Calgary, Alberta there are a few technical groups that I'd suggest grads use to help them build up that network in face to face forms first. There are also possible LinkedIn groups and other social media groups that may be useful to consider in building up contacts and connections. Do you have a LinkedIn profile up to date?
3. Career fairs - Some places will have these on a regular basis that may be a great way to meet a number of companies and talk to people that work there. Is there one coming up near you when school ends? Some schools will have fairs and some cities may have them depending on how many schools are in the area.
4. Leverage your existing network - Who do you currently know that knows of a company with a possible opening in what you want to do? This is using people you already know rather than adding to things. Some people will find opportunities this way.

Comment: I will use school resources as well in addition to the job websites for sure. I will surely contact my former supervisor & ask him if he knows people at other companies. :)